# Preventing horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that slides in from offscreen. There's no horizontal scrollbar showing, but you can still slide the screen manually (in IE and Chrome, not Firefox) and see the offscreen div in the horizontal overflow. Obviously, I really want it hidden.

A simple example (without the javascript to make the offscreen div slide in) can be seen at https://jsfiddle.net/7g0x96hs/ and below:

```
<div id="maintext">I'd like the footer to display below, but the offscreen div to the left to not be visible by scrolling.</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<div id="offscreen"></div>


body{
overflow-x:hidden;    
}

#footer{
position:absolute;
top:1000px;
width:100%;
height:10px;
background-color:#000000;           
}

#offscreen{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:1200;
background-color:#000000;
right:-100%;
top:0; 
}
```

How can I ensure the user cannot manually move the page horizontally? overflow-x:hidden on the body (or a wrapper div) doesn't work... Seems to be the vertical scroll that's causing the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `overflow : hidden;` seems to deactivate the manual vertical scrollbar (see more in [Your Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7g0x96hs/)).

Comment: Works just fine for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and get the same issue in IE. Actually, I've just found that changing the offscreen position to "relative" in the fiddle corrects the issue - now just trying to translate it to the actual webpage!